# Exception Property [ ] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-6

I'm trying to get the id of the students that took an exam. I'm using relationships in Laravel and i don't know what i'm missing. Here is the code :

**My models**

*The exam model :*

```
class Examen extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];


    public function professor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Professor::class,'prof_id');
    }

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }

    public function examen_passers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Examen_passer::class);
    }
}
```

*The exam taking model :*

```
class Examen_passer extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function examen()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Examen::class);
    }

    public function reponses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reponse::class);
    }

      public function reponsestxt()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reponsetxt::class);
    }
}
```

**My controller :**

```
public function corriger()
    {
 $examen = Examen::where('prof_id',Auth::guard('professor')->id())->get();
 dd($examen->examen_passers->etudiant_id);

}
```

Comment: Or even with : foreach($examen as $examen)
        {
            echo $examen->examen_passers->etudiant_id;
        }

Comment: the output of $examen is a collection you cannot call examen_passers function on the collection, use first() instead of get()

Comment: Thank you ! Now i understand.

Comment: you're welcome, but please note that first will return one record, if you need all the records keep using get but then you will have to loop on the output to get etudiant_id, this is one way, you have other ways(eager load,...) depending on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck) to get all ids from your passers collection:

```
$examen->examen_passers->pluck('etudiant_id');
```

This method will take the value of `etudiant_id` from every item in your collection and return them together in an array.